# The element doesn't appear when I set its position to absolute

Tags: html, css

Here I have three elements which have **position: absolute.**

**First** and **Second** elements are OK, but the **third** element just doesn't appear.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

#first {
  border: solid green;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
}

#second {
  border: solid blue;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
}

#third {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: solid brown;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <section id="first"></section>
  <section id="second"> </section>
  <section id="third"></section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve] here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `position: absolute` on an element, it's removed from the normal flow of the document. When you do that to all of the direct children of an element, it ends up collapsing down and has a `height` of `0`. If you use the web inspector you can confirm that your container, in this case, `body`, is `0px` tall.

Setting the `bottom` property on `#third` causes it to align with the bottom of the `body` element, which is at the top of the viewport, which subsequently results in your element being rendered above the viewport where you can't see it.

If you set a fixed `height` or `min-height` on the `body` you can resolve this. A common pattern is to set the minimum height for the body to be the height of the viewport:

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Thnx for the response!  But setting min-height of the body to 100vh is the viewport height, so its position always changes depending on the screen size, but what if I want to position relative to the whole document, I mean, what if I want to position smth to the footer, for exp.

Comment: In short words, let's say I have 'body' and I want all the children to be positioned relative to it and we know that 'body' is the first positioned parent to each of them

Comment: I think you're over-thinking this. You're asking to position all of the elements relative to their parent container, which is fine, but the parent container needs dimension in order to do that. By default, HTML elements get their dimension from their children/contents. You'll probably find an easier path to the desired layout by relying on this rather than attempting to subvert it.

Comment: Exactly! When I set a particular body height (for exp: 'body: 1000px') it works fine which should be, but is there a way to do that without setting body height in px, so that, the body height will get its dimensions from the children?

Comment: If you want all children relative to the body then you don't have to specify `position:relative;` in body.. **By default, body will be relative element unless we force any other element to be relative.** So just removing the `position:relative;` from the body will fix your problem as well. If you don't want to remove it then you have to specify the `height` or `min-height` as @coreyward explained.

Comment: Honestly, you are getting some side effects from the way that `body` is treated by browsers. You probably want to wrap your content in another element (e.g. `div`) and stop using `position: absolute` because, as I opened with, it removes the element from the document flow, meaning parents will not treat the dimensions of that child as contents when determining their size or position.